# Short film about predicting a child's future

Tags: story-identification, short-film

Around ten years ago, I saw a short film on YouTube about a parent taking their child to a machine which would then simulate their future.  The future the machine simulated for the child started out with her playing around in a grass field. As she played, flowers would sprout and small animals would appear that she would also play with. In the mid teens the simulation took a darker turn.  She found a black vine in a canyon, which she then touched. I don't remember if touching it changed something about her physically or just made what she touched sprout the black vine. The last scene of the simulation i think was her at a podium giving a speech while clad in dark colors while below her marched endless ranks of people in uniform.  The film ended with the machine stating something along the lines that the child has high levels of aggression and asked whether the parent wanted to keep the child and then the parent making the choice to keep the child.

I believe the film was called "Oracle" but I haven't been able to find it.  I think the film was not in English and I was watching with subtitles.  Around the same time I also saw "Sintel", so it might also have been made in Blender.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here ; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Hmmm.  I read a short story like that.  Long, long ago.   Mom and dad keep having the prediction run on various combinations, and it keeps coming up bad.  Like, sometimes the kid winds up killing the mom, or the dad, or both.  Seems the dad figures out that the problem isn't the kid but the mother.  So, he tells his wife that things will work out fine in this one combination - but it is one in which she gets killed.  The mom and dad get the results individually for some reason.  The test/prediction/simulation is done before the child is even conceived.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The film is [*Oracle*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2816112/), a 2007 animated short from France, directed by Sébastien Buisson, Michael Desnoyelles, Tristan Le Granché, and Flavien Lens, with music by Mylcis.

The film's [poster](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BMTc5ODYwMjc3OV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDExMjQ1MDE@._V1_SY1000_CR0,0,707,1000_AL_.jpg) shows what looks a test tube and a fidget spinner. The spinner also appears in the title sequence:

[image]

> Around ten years ago

The film was released in late 2007 and made the festival rounds in 2007 and 2008. The film had a website; however, whatever is currently at the film's domain gets flagged as malware, so don't try to visit it directly. The content from 2008 is mostly navigable at the [Internet Archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20081017184906/http://www.oracle-lefilm.com:80/) as is a [review](http://web.archive.org/web/20080607232303/http://www.scifi-universe.com:80/fiche_actu.asp?id=6690) on Sci-Fi Universe.

> I saw a short film

This film is just under 8 minutes long.

> on YouTube

The film is still available on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhIzVXyZkE0).

> a parent taking their child to a machine which would then simulate their future. The future the machine simulated for the child started out with her playing around in a grass field. As she played, flowers would sprout and small animals would appear that she would also play with.

This film starts with a dad being spoken to by a disembodied voice. There is a little dialogue at the beginning, but I don't speak French and this upload doesn't have subtitles.

I think it's saying something like "What parent wouldn't want to know their child's future? (something something) ... the choice ..."

[image: Dad watching simulation]

Then a baby appears, and some waving grass, and the baby starts bouncing through the grass, and flowers appear:

[image: Toddler running through grass and flowers]

After the baby scenes, there are scenes of a young preadolescent child touching the ground and flowers and trees appearing:

[image: Young child in grass with one flowering plant]
[image: Young child with palm trees]

> In the mid teens the simulation took a darker turn. She found a black vine in a canyon, which she then touched. I don't remember if touching it changed something about her physically or just made what she touched sprout the black vine.

When she is 16, she is wandering through a canyon full of strange plants and happens across a spiny cactus-looking thing.

[image: Teen with spiky plant]

After she touches it, it sprouts black viny runners:

[image: Teen with sprouting vine]

She defiantly slaps her hand on the canyon wall and allows the vine to take her over:

[image: Teen being possessed by vine]

When the vine recedes, we see that she has been transformed:

[image: Teen transformed into evil queen]

> The last scene of the simulation i think was her at a podium giving a speech while clad in dark colors while below her marched endless ranks of people in uniform.

She summons or generates an army of marching soldiers and stands before them, not on a podium, but on an outcropping of rock:

[image: Evil queen standing above thousands of soldiers in ranks]

> The film ended with the machine stating something along the lines that the child has high levels of aggression and asked whether the parent wanted to keep the child and then the parent making the choice to keep the child.

After the simulation, the dad is breathless and concerned. The disembodied voice speaks to him (in French), and there are two buttons before him: Accepter (red) and Refuser (green). He takes a deep breath and slaps the Accepter button:

[image: Dad's hand on Accepter button]

A pod comes out and opens to reveal his baby:

[image: New baby in pod]

> I believe the film was called "Oracle" but I haven't been able to find it. I think the film was not in English and I was watching with subtitles. Around the same time I also saw "Sintel", so it might also have been made in Blender.

Correct on the title, correct that it's not in English.

Comment: Well, it looks like i should have looked at YouTube more. I had a version of this bookmarked, but the channel that had posted it had been removed because of copyright claims. After seeing this i found a [version with English subtitles](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lk6KbB_TXg0)